# MongoDB Aggregate query with AND condition

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this MongoDB query in PHP:

```
$data = $collection->aggregate(
    array('$match' => array(
        'PATIENT_ID' => $singoloPatientId
    )),
    array('$group' => array(
        '_id' => '$PATIENT_ID',
        'massi1' => array(
            '$max' => $dnameth_value
        )
    ))
);
```

which works. Now I want to add another where condition with AND:

```
experiment = $experimentInput
```

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

**try this**

```
$data=$collection->aggregate(
    array('$match'=> array(
        '$and' => array(
            'PATIENT_ID'=>$singoloPatientId,
            'experiment'=>$experimentInput
            ))),
    array('$group' => array(
        '_id' => '$PATIENT_ID',
        'massi1' => array(
            '$max' => $dnameth_value
        )
    ))
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: if its helpful for you then don't forget to upvote  ;)

Comment: I have not yet 15 reputation points and then unfortunately I can not vote. sorry

Comment: Hi @mongoDB if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. You don't need any reputation to accept the answer but there is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Just append the expression with the condition to the existing **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** query:

```
$data = $collection->aggregate(
    array('$match' => array(
        'PATIENT_ID' => $singoloPatientId,
        'experiment' => $experimentInput
    )),
    array('$group' => array(
        '_id' => '$PATIENT_ID',
        'massi1' => array(
            '$max' => $dnameth_value
        )
    ))
);
```

From the **[docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/)**:

> MongoDB provides an implicit `AND` operation when specifying a comma
>   separated list of expressions. Using an explicit `AND` with the **[`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/)**
>   operator is necessary when the same field or operator has to be
>   specified in multiple expressions.

Comment: Thank you very much